# Output an error message when someone enters a letter as a menu choice?

Tags: java

This program works well but I want to make this program tell the user that no letters should be used there are only options 1 to 5. Can someone please help me in figuring that out?

```
public class Main {

Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/

public static void main(String[] args) {
int UserIn=0;
double numberInputA;
double numberInputB;
double Answer;


Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

while (UserIn!=5){ //this starts while loop when user input is not equal to 5
System.out.println ("What type of calculation would you like to perform?");
System.out.println ( "1. Add\n2. Subtract\n" +
"3. Multiply\n4. Divide\n5. Exit");//shows the menu
UserIn = input.nextInt();//ask user to input integer of choice

if (UserIn>5){
System.out.println( "ERROR choose the numbers on the menu" );
}else if (UserIn<1){
    System.out.println("ERROR choose the numbers on the menu");
}
```

Comment: It'll blow up if it gets a String or Character anyway.  You'd want to catch that exception and do something with it. *Hint hint*

Comment: @jon Soiv Where is the exact problem?

Comment: This sounds like a joke, you can may be show a Message before prompting for input, "Please enter numerics", if you are lazy to do a `try catch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int UserIn = 0;
    double numberInputA;
    double numberInputB;
    double Answer;

    while (UserIn != 5) { //this starts while loop when user input is not equal to 5
        System.out.println("What type of calculation would you like to perform?");
        System.out.println("1. Add\n2. Subtract\n"
                + "3. Multiply\n4. Divide\n5. Exit");//shows the menu
        UserIn = getUserInput();
    }
}

private static int getUserInput() {
    int UserIn = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        UserIn = input.nextInt();//ask user to input integer of choice
        if (UserIn > 5) {
            System.out.println("ERROR choose the numbers on the menu");
            return -1;
        } else if (UserIn < 1) {
            System.out.println("ERROR choose the numbers on the menu");
            return -1;
        }
        return UserIn;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR only numbers are allowed");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `if-else-if` to show exact same message. Instead you can use only `if()` with `&&` to reduce complexity.